# How could I execute 'apt-get install' on docker ubuntu contain?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker

firstly, I installed and ran docker contain using below command.

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Then I executed below commands.

```
root@d444a77039e7:/# apt-get update
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.200)]
```

It blocked all the time.

Then I ran the below command, but met issues.

```
root@d444a77039e7:/# apt-get install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nodejs
```

Then I set the http and https proxy like below, but it failed as well.

```
root@d444a77039e7:/# export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.xxx.com
root@d444a77039e7:/# export HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.xxx.com
```

Could you tell me how can I fix this issue? thanks. My host machine is redhat5.9 which does not support latest version of nodejs. So I plan to install it on docker engine.

Comment: On a related note, if you want to make sure you get a recent version of node (many distro repos do not update often), you can follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions).

Answer (score 0):

Try with small letters.

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.xxx.com
export https_proxy=http://proxy.xxx.com
```

The proper way to overtake this issue is, you can create a new image with below `Dockerfile`, with that, you needn't manually set it any more.

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV http_proxy http://proxy.xxx.com
ENV https_proxy http://proxy.xxx.com
```

Comment: @askb I saw you edit my answer directly with wrong answer. You shouldn't  do that, it is ok to correct the spelling or something else, but not the code. If you has some suggestions, please follow with comments.

Comment: what you try to change is, you think proxy server has to be https when  https rquest, that not always. In most case, we have only one proxy server for both http and https requests.

Comment: apologies for this, as I may have got this mixed up. Your answer had two entries for `ENV` pointing to the same proxy url, but `https_proxy` mentioned for the `Dockerfile`, thought you may have missed out https in the earlier export aswell.

Answer (score 0):

That means your docker build has not been started with the [new docker 1.9+ build-arg arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg). That will avoid putting the full proxy (which can include sometimes your credentials) in the Dockerfile:

> You can use `ENV` instructions in a Dockerfile to define variable values. These values persist in the built image. However, often persistence is not what you want. Users want to specify variables differently depending on which host they build an image on.
>
> A good example is `http_proxy` or source versions for pulling intermediate files. The `ARG` instruction lets `Dockerfile` authors define values that users can set at build-time using the `--build-arg` flag:

```
$ docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234 .
```

> This flag allows you to pass the build-time variables that are accessed like regular environment variables in the `RUN` instruction of the `Dockerfile`. Also, these values don’t persist in the intermediate or final images like `ENV` values do.

Comment: Thanks. But I was using the docker image(ubuntu image) provided by docker hub, I can not make any changes of it.

Comment: @liamxu the image has nothing to do with the docker version installed on the *host*: you need the latest docker on your host, and then build/use any docker image you want.